# how to put sqlite db on sdcard from assets

Tags: android, sqlite, sd-card

I have 7mb app that consumes 25mb once the sqlite db is copied to the data/data/packagename/database folder. This is too big on my frugal emulator and potentially offensive to users.

Is there a way to put the sqlite db straight onto the sdcard? Or the whole app et al? Asking users to force it across after installation seems too little too late and i can't  host the dayabase myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to put the sqlite db straight onto the sdcard?

You could probably make a mod to [`SQLiteAssetHelper`](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper) to handle this. By default, it will place the database in the normal spot on internal storage. Unfortunately, right now, it would require some non-trivial surgery to make this change, though I have just filed [a feature request](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper/issues/4) to make that a bit easier.

> Or the whole app et al?

You can [use `android:installLocation="preferExternal"`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/install-location.html), though it may not be honored. And, that will not affect your database -- `getFilesDir()`, `getDatabaseDir()`, and kin are always on internal storage.

Also note that this is all really only an issue for Android 1.x/2.x devices. Everything newer than that should consider internal and external storage to be on one partition, so they share space.